# DLL load failed. The specific module could not be found while importing 'from sklearn.cluster import KMeans'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

In the statement 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans Im getting the following error:
'DLL load failed. The specific module could not be found'C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py---from ._logistic_sigmoid import _log_logistic_sigmoid

Im using Python 3.4 and scikit_learn 0.16.1

Comment: your installation of scikit-learn is broken. You may want to try to reinstall and if that does not work tell us exactly how you installed it in the first place.

Comment: I tried to install the same as before  through command prompt and got the following--C:\>C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install "D:/Aparna/python/libraries/scikit_learn-0.1
6.1-cp34-none-win32.whl"
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scikit-learn==0.16.1 f
rom file:///D:/Aparna/python/libraries/scikit_learn-0.16.1-cp34-none-win32.whl i
n c:\python34\lib\site-packages